# Rails, Paperclip uploads to Amazon S3 not working with Amazon RDS but working with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-rds

I'm using Paperclip with Rails to upload pictures to Amazon S3 and my application is deployed on Heroku.

Now when I use the database provided by Heroku (postgres), the uploads work prefectly.

However, the moment I switch to using Amazon RDS, the upload doesn't work.

Note: there are no issues with setting up RDS as the rest of the application works perfectly, its just the picture uploads that stop working.

My guess is that, maybe (some how) when paperclip wants to put an entry into the pictures table, it cannot access the database when its on RDS, but can access it just fine when using the Heroku assigned Postgres database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Paperclip is using the database through ActiveRecord. This seems not to be the issue. Have you has a look into your production.log? Are there exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your paperclip field as  **attr_accessible** For example in my code

```
class VenueImage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :venue

  has_attached_file :image, 
    :styles => { :large => "1200x900#", :medium => "800x600#", :thumb=> "100x100#" }

  validates_attachment_presence :image

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, 
    :content_type => %r{image/.*}, 
    :less_than => 1.megabyte

  attr_accessible :image

end
```

This is just a rough guess and it doesn't make sense that it would work under postgres and not under RDS but **attr_accessible** is always a case to trip up on and worth checking. If this is the problem then you will see something like

```
Cannot mass assign attribute 'image'
```

in your logs

Comment: Figured it out.  When the uploads were working locally (mysql) and not on RDS (also mysql).  I realized it wasn't the database.  The logs showed an error occurring on @picture.save, so I realized there was an error when saving the file.  when I compared the pictures table locally vs RDS I realized that one of the fields was set to NOT NULL on RDS but not locally, and of course I wasn't setting that field, hence the error.  I must have changed the field manually locally, but forgot to update the migration.  an issue of bad rails practice :P.  Thanks for your response btw

Comment: However, I still don't understand how it was working on Postgres